# T-Sql Update Problem

Tags: sql, insert-update

`Update Inv01 Set PrintStat = 1 where Inv_No = '335059'`

This query taking too much time even nine minutes finished.Please help me

Comment: How many records do you have with an `Inv_No` of `'335059'`?

Comment: Have you checked Activity Monitor in SQL Server Management Studio to see if something is blocking the update?

Comment: Have you looked at the query plan? How many rows are in `Inv01`?  What's the definition of your index on `Inv_No`?

Comment: How can i find through activity monitor?

Answer (score 2):

Index your `Inv01` table on the `Inv_No` column, that's the only way you're going to speed it up; there's no way to improve the query itself.

Comment: Is it a multi-column or a single column index on Inv_No? Is the optimizer using the index during the update?

Comment: Multicolumn index. how can i find whether optimizer is using?

Comment: i found exclusive lock while updating ?

Comment: What's your transaction isolation level?